How do I code for different wavelet decompositions?
I want to compare an image denoising method's performance using different wavelets and decomposition levels but I can't seem to incorporate the decomposition levels. Here's my current code (that works):
% Load dataset
original = imread('brain_mri_transversal_t2_001.jpg'); % original image filename
noisy = imread('mri_image_noisy.jpg'); % Load noisy image

% Apply wavelet transform
[LL, LH, HL, HH] = dwt2(noisy, 'db4');

% Define the threshold value
t = 200;                  % Adjust the threshold value as needed
%t = rbe*sqrt(2*log(1000));      % tuni VisuShrink

% Define the function for adaptive thresholding
function coeff_thresh = adaptive_thresholding(coeff, threshold, rbe)
    if threshold == rbe
        % Adaptive Hard Thresholding for t = rbe
        coeff_thresh = zeros(size(coeff));
        coeff_thresh(coeff < -threshold) = coeff(coeff < -threshold);
        coeff_thresh(abs(coeff) <= threshold) = ...
            rbe*(exp((-coeff(abs(coeff) <= threshold).^2)/(2*(rbe^2))-1/2)) - rbe*(exp((-0)/(2*(rbe^2))-1/2));
        coeff_thresh(coeff > threshold) = coeff(coeff > threshold);
    elseif threshold > rbe
        % IMPROVED AGGD for t > rbe
        coeff_thresh = zeros(size(coeff));
        coeff_thresh(coeff < -threshold) = coeff(coeff < -threshold).*(1./(1+exp(coeff(coeff < -threshold)+threshold))-threshold/2);
        coeff_thresh(abs(coeff) <= threshold) = ...
            rbe*(exp((-coeff(abs(coeff) <= threshold).^2)/(2*(rbe^2))-1/2)) - rbe*(exp((-0)/(2*(rbe^2))-1/2));
        coeff_thresh(coeff > threshold) = coeff(coeff > threshold).*(1./(1+exp(coeff(coeff > threshold)+threshold))+threshold/2);
    end
end

% Robust median estimator 
rbe = median(abs(HH(:)))/0.6745;

% Threshold the wavelet coefficients
HH_thresh = adaptive_thresholding(HH, t, rbe);
LH_thresh = adaptive_thresholding(LH, t, rbe);
HL_thresh = adaptive_thresholding(HL, t, rbe);

% Inverse wavelet transform
reconstructed = idwt2(LL, LH_thresh, HL_thresh, HH_thresh, 'db4');


I tried using wavedec2 and waverec2 but I always get some error about having too many input/output arguments, having not enough input arguments etc.

In MATLAB, you need to write functions at the end of the code or in another script. This code in its current form would give errors. I couldn't understand the part on different decomposition levels, can you provide the exact part of the code that gives you error?

I'm not an expert on these libraries but the documentation of dwt2 says Single-level 2-D discrete wavelet transform. For a multi-level transform you would need to use wavedec2.
